# Cannot Change String To Date Formate in Symfony 2.7

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.7

OK, tried to debug this problem for a few days and now i give up.
I have the followig form builder

```
  Builder
    ->add('passDate', 'hidden', array('data'=>null, 'empty_data'=> date('Y-m-d',strtotime('1950-10-10'))))
    ->add('TDVLFirstIssue', 'hidden', array('data'=>null, 'empty_data'=> date('Y-m-d',strtotime('1950-10-10'))))
    ->add('TDVLExpiryDate', 'hidden', array('data'=>null, 'empty_data'=> date('Y-m-d',strtotime('2017-10-10'))));
```

and this is my entity

```
/**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="passDate", type="date")
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $passDate;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="tdvlIssue", type="date")
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $TDVLFirstIssue;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @Assert\GreaterThan(value = "+1 day midnight", message="Your TDVL require at least 1 month validity.")
     * @ORM\Column(name="tdvlExpiry", type="date")
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $TDVLExpiryDate;

public function setPassDate($passDate)
    {
        $this->passDate = $passDate;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get passDate
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getPassDate()
    {
        return $this->passDate;
    }

public function setTDVLFirstIssue($tDVLFirstIssue)
    {
        $this->TDVLFirstIssue = $tDVLFirstIssue;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get tDVLFirstIssue
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getTDVLFirstIssue()
    {
        return $this->TDVLFirstIssue;
    }
**
     * Set tDVLExpiryDate
     *
     * @param \DateTime $tDVLExpiryDate
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setTDVLExpiryDate($tDVLExpiryDate)
    {
        $this->TDVLExpiryDate = $tDVLExpiryDate;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get tDVLExpiryDate
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getTDVLExpiryDate()
    {
        return $this->TDVLExpiryDate;
    }
```

And here is my controller

```
$entity = new User();
$form = $this->createSystemUserForm($entity);
$form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
         $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
         $entity->setTDVLFirstIssue(date('Y-m-d',strtotime('1950-10-10')));
         $entity->setTDVLExpiryDate(date('Y-m-d',strtotime('2018-10-10')));
         $entity->setPassDate(date('Y-m-d',strtotime('1950-10-10')));
    }
```

What i am trying to do is i want to pass default date to the database. so i tried with vanilla php format converting function data and format . But when i submit the form, it throw me this error which is

> Error: Call to a member function format() on string

```
public function convertToDatabaseValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
{
    return ($value !== null)
        ? $value->format($platform->getDateFormatString()) : null;
}
```

. I  understood that `$passDate`, `$TDVLFirstIssue` and `$TDVLExpiryDate` cannot be blank , which defined in entity as `NotBlank()`. I suspect that it is because of unsuccessful string to date conversion. So can help me about this problem? thanks in advance. 
Note: Please take note that i am using symfony 2.7.

Comment: new \DateTime('now')

Comment: new \DateTime() is the same as new \DateTime('now')

Answer (score 1):

I change my builder date as follow and it works.

```
builder
->add('passDate', 'hidden', array('data'=>null, 'empty_data'=> date_create('1950-10-10')))
->add('TDVLFirstIssue', 'hidden', array('data'=>null, 'empty_data'=> date_create('1950-10-10')))
->add('TDVLExpiryDate', 'hidden', array('data'=>null, 'empty_data'=> date_create('2017-10-10')));
```

Hope it helps.